# Perl - can't use string (...) as an array ref

Tags: arrays, string, perl, file-io

I'm practicing Perl with a challenge from codeeval.com, and I'm getting an unexpected error. The goal is to iterate through a file line-by-line, in which each line has a string and a character separated by a comma, and to find the right-most occurrence of that character in the string. I was getting wrong answers back, so I altered the code to print out just variable values, when I got the following error:

`Can't use string ("Hello world") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at char_pos.pl line 20, <FILE> line 1.`

My code is below. You can see a sample from the file in the header. You can also see the original output code, which was incorrectly only displaying the right-most character in each string.

```
#CodeEval challenge: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/31/
#Call with $> char_pos.pl numbers
##Hello world, d
##Hola mundo, H
##Keyboard, b
##Connecticut, n

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = $ARGV[0];

open FILE, $path or die $!;

my $len;

while(<FILE>)
{
    my @args = split(/,/,$_);
    $len = length($args[0]) - 1;
    print "$len\n";
    for(;$len >= 0; $len--)
    {
        last if $args[0][$len] == $args[1];
    }


    #if($len > -1)
    #{
    # print $len, "\n";   
    #}else
    #{
    # print "not found\n";   
    #}

}
```

**EDIT:**
Based on the answers below, here's the code that I got to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;


open my $fh,"<",shift;

while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my @args = split(/,/,$line);
    my $index = rindex($args[0],$args[1]);

    print $index>-1 ? "$index\n" : "Not found\n";
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Check `perldoc substr` instead of `$args[0][$len]` and use `eq` if you're comparing strings.

Comment: And use `while (<>) { … }` instead of explicitly opening files, etc; it is much more idiomatic Perl.  And while you're checking the docs (noting that it needs to be `perldoc -f substr` to look up the function `substr` by name), look up `perldoc -f rindex`.  You might want to split on `/, */` to allow for the space before the trailing letter.

Comment: Tip: You might prefer `my ($word, $letter) = split(/,/,$_);`. `@args` is rather poor name.

Comment: I'd tend to avoid the `$_` in the `split` as well. `split ( /,/ );` will do the same thing.

Comment: @ikegami - I like that approach to split. I'll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to know a bit about Perl functions. Perl has many functions for strings and scalars and it's not always possible to know them all right off the top of your head.

However, Perl has a great function called [rindex](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rindex.html) that does exactly what you want. You give it a string, a *substring* (in this case, a single character), and it looks for the first position of that substring from the ***right*** side of the string (the [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rindex.html) does the same thing from the left hand side.)

Since you're learning Perl, it may be a good idea to get a few books on *Modern* Perl and standard coding practices. This way, you know newer coding techniques and the standard coding practices.

- [Modern Perl](http://www.powells.com/biblio?PID=30019&cgi=product&isbn=9780985451943) - Gives you newer programming help.
- [Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do) - An old standard.
- [Perl Best Practices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do) - The standard coding practices.

Here's a sample program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

open my $fh, "<", shift;

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($string, $char) = split /,/, $line, 2;
    if ( length $char != 1 or not defined $string ) {
        say qq(Invalid line "$line".);
        next;
    }
    my $location = rindex $string, $char;
    if ( $location != -1 ) {
        say qq(The right most "$char" is at position $location in "$string".);
    }
    else {
        say qq(The character "$char" wasn't found in line "$line".)";
}
close $fh;
```

A few suggestions:

- `use autodie` allows your program to automatically die on bad `open`. No need to check.
- Three parameter `open` statement is now considered de rigueur.
- Use scalar variables for file handles. They're easier to pass into subroutines.
- Use lexically scoped variables for loops. Try to avoid using `$_`.
- Always do a `chomp` after a read.

And most importantly, ***error check***! I check the format of the line to make sure that's there is only a single comma, and that the character I'm searching for is a character. I also check the exit value of `rindex` to make sure it found the character. If `rindex` doesn't find the character, it returns a `-1`.

Also know that the first character in a line is `0` and not `1`. You may need to *adjust* for this depending what output you're expecting.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the thorough answer! I'll make sure to check out those resources. Perl isn't my favorite language, but it helps to have clear, detailed explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in perl are a basic type, not subscriptable arrays.  You would use the [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function to get individual characters (which are also just strings) or substrings from them.

Also note that string comparison is done with `eq`; `==` is numeric comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($i=<DATA>){
($string,$char)=split(",",$i);
push(@str,$string);}
@join=split("",$_), print "$join[-1]\n",foreach(@str);



__DATA__
Hello world, d
Hola mundo, H
Keyboard, b
Connecticut, n
```